# my app is not for all devices in market

Tags: android, google-play

Today, I placed our new app onto the market store. It can be found by most mobile phones - unfortunately, it cannot be detected by one specific model which is used by one of our customers. It is the Vodafone 845, with a small screen (240x320p) and low density (120 dpi). It's running with Android 2.1, updated version (i.e. SDK 7), and has all the necessary hardware (GPS, cam, and internet access), but, however, doesn't detect the app in the market.
I have already tried anyDensity="true".
The app is free, not copy protected, and open to all countries.
I have the following settings in the manifest:

```
  xmlns:android="xxx"
  package="xxx"
  android:versionCode="10"
  android:versionName="1">
  <supports-screens

      android:largeScreens="true"
      android:normalScreens="true"
      android:smallScreens="true"          
 />  
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity 
      android:name=".CamaraView"
      android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
      android:screenOrientation="landscape"
      android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"

              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
    android:name=".ResultView"
    android:configChanges="orientation"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    />      

</application>
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: recheck manifest android:anyDenisty=true is missing from the manifest you posted

Answer (score 0):

Against which SDK version is the app developed? If you have 1.6 or higher you should read this: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: It is developed for android 2.1 (SDK 7). It tried things like:

Comment: <supports-screens
          android:largeScreens="true"
          android:normalScreens="true"
          android:smallScreens="true"
          android:anyDensity="true" />
  </manifest>

I also have

<uses-sdk
 android:minSdkVersion="7"
 android:targetSdkVersion="7"
 />

Are there any other posiblitys?
Thx

Comment: You can try: `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" android:targetSdkVersion="7" />`

Comment: But then the app will crash in runtime when someone use it on android 1.5